# "aapt.exe" exited with code 255

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.android, azure-devops, aapt

Trying to setup my build server for Xamarin Android builds, but i constantly keeps getting into this issue:

> [error]C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1832,3):
>   Error MSB6006: "aapt.exe" exited with code 255.

Anyone know what this error code means? We dont have this issue on the teams local computers. So i assume i am missing something on the build machine, but cannot figure out what.

- Visual Studio Team Services Build Agent
- MS 2012 R2 Datacenter
- Visual Studio 2015 Community
- Android SDK Manager w/all SDK's up til revision 24
- Xamarin 6.1.1.0

Comment: Diagnostic Build Output should give you all the answers you need:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: Make sure you have all the required SDK version installed on the build agent. Same issue here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27258/xamarin-android-common-targets-783-2-error-msb6006-aapt-exe-exited-with-code-255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a problem in build tool. So, can you compare the installed build tool version in your local machine and build machine.

[image]

Note: Add the following line under PropertyGroup tag in your project file to specify the build tool version.

```
<AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>23.0.3</AndroidSdkBuildToolsVersion>
```

Comment: For some reason it did not like the tools for revision 24

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are probably missing some files in your SDK manager for android. Open the sdk manager and ensure you have downloaded all API levels you are targeting as well as the up to date build tools and extras.

[image]